# input matrices of ints into cblas_sgemm returns all 0s

Tags: c, blas

I'm trying to use cblas_sgemm to do fast matrix multiplication on two matrices of ints.

Right now it's returning all zeroes.

I ran a quick naive matrix multiply to double check the expected output data and they are not supposed to be zeroes.

The **working** naive approach:

```
typedef int    mm_data_t;

void func1( mm_data_t *in1, mm_data_t *in2,  mm_data_t *out, int N ){
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(k=0; k<N; k++){
            int temp = in1[i*N+k];
            for(j=0; j<N; j++){
                out[i*N+j] += temp * in2[k*N+j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And using cblas_sgemm:

```
void func2( mm_data_t *in1, mm_data_t *in2,  mm_data_t *out, int N ){

    cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, N,  N,  N, 1.0, (float*)in1, N, (float*)in2, N, 0.0, (float*)out, N);

}
```

I'm using one dimensional arrays for optimization.

Input data is black box'd but are constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cblas_sgemm()` is designed to multiply matrices of single-precision *floating point* values, not integers.

So your integers are being interpreted as floating point values. Small positive integers are likely to be treated as [subnormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number).  Multiplying any pair of these will have a result of zero.  So if your inputs are all small non-negative integers, the outputs  will be all zeros.

And if your inputs contain small negative integers, your outputs will probably contain a lot of [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)s, which will look like very large integers (which may be positive or negative.)

If you really need to multiply integers, you will need to convert them to & from floating point, or use a library that can multiply matrices of integers (BLAS cannot.)